# Build Remote Event Receiver with yaml

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-receivers

Is there are a way build the Remote Event Receiver project from PowerShell?

We have a RER project and we want to obtain the `.app` file without the interface, just pure PowerShell script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, necessary to use **Visual Studio**.

You could refer to **[this article](https://www.spguides.com/remote-event-receivers-in-sharepoint-online/)** to create remote event receiver in SharePoint Online.

Then, you could run the following **pnp PowerShell** command:

```
Add-PnPEventReceiver -Name "TestEventReceiver" -Url https://yourserver.azurewebsites.net/eventreceiver.svc -EventReceiverType WebAdding -Synchronization Synchronous
```

Add a new remote event receiver that is executed while a new subsite is being created